# Changing axes' origin adds weird whitespace

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, coordinates

I would like to display points in a Tikz picture, whose y components are all negative. That is per se no problem, but I want the y axis to be a bit higher than the x axis to emphasize the negative values.

See the screenshots below the code.

In another file with different data I got it perfectly working using [Jake's approach to move the coordinate axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62431/38074). However, in the file below increasing the y intersection coordinate (`axis line origin={0,THIS}`) only adds weird whitespace before the Tikz picture.
No warnings (except the one for *filecontents*) are shown.

**What is the reason for this behavior? How can I fix it?**

(Note: I'm also open to suggestions not involving Jake's code anymore as long as my desired result is produced.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

% Author:  Jake <https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake>
% Link:    https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62431/38074
% License: CC BY-SA 3.0
\pgfplotsset{
    axis line origin/.style args={#1,#2}{
        x filter/.append code={ % Check for empty or filtered out numbers
                \ifx\pgfmathresult\empty\else\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-#1}\fi
            },
        y filter/.append code={
                \ifx\pgfmathresult\empty\else\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-#2}\fi
            },
        xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{\tick+#1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},
        yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{\tick+#2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Data
t;x;y
0.000000000E0;6.348840913E-4;9.925120686E-4
8.333333333E-3;5.838627285E-4;4.724618695E-4
1.666666667E-2;1.094161960E-3;-2.700310368E-3
2.500000000E-2;7.550411425E-4;-5.097581518E-3
3.333333333E-2;6.794111604E-4;-9.011432646E-3
4.166666667E-2;3.461038282E-4;-1.562674575E-2
5.000000000E-2;1.282057031E-4;-1.909622209E-2
5.833333333E-2;-3.401256682E-4;-2.518409682E-2
1.408333333E0;-3.104116765E-2;-1.739549231E0
1.416666667E0;-3.322785461E-2;-1.740279419E0
1.425000000E0;-3.599135975E-2;-1.742337105E0
1.433333333E0;-3.808925614E-2;-1.744682891E0
1.541666667E0;-7.108984101E-2;-1.839024730E0
1.550000000E0;-7.297102460E-2;-1.857275769E0
1.558333333E0;-7.571494352E-2;-1.870979850E0
1.566666667E0;-7.854608723E-2;-1.892338940E0
1.575000000E0;-8.274961995E-2;-1.897014288E0
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=right,
            axis y line=left,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line origin={0,0.5},
            xlabel=Time,
            ylabel=x,
            xticklabel style={inner xsep=0pt, anchor=north west},
            xtick={0},
            after end axis/.code={
                \path (axis cs:0,0)
                node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.075cm] {0};
            }
        ]
            \addplot[color=red,ultra thick] table [
                skip first n=1,
                col sep=semicolon,
                x=t,
                y=y
            ] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image: Actual result]

The result I'd like:

[image: Wanted result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what result exactly you're looking for, but if you only want to extend the ordinate line upwards a bit, you can set `enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.2}`. A value of `0.2` extends the axis by 20 %.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Data
t;x;y
0.000000000E0;6.348840913E-4;9.925120686E-4
8.333333333E-3;5.838627285E-4;4.724618695E-4
1.666666667E-2;1.094161960E-3;-2.700310368E-3
2.500000000E-2;7.550411425E-4;-5.097581518E-3
3.333333333E-2;6.794111604E-4;-9.011432646E-3
4.166666667E-2;3.461038282E-4;-1.562674575E-2
5.000000000E-2;1.282057031E-4;-1.909622209E-2
5.833333333E-2;-3.401256682E-4;-2.518409682E-2
1.408333333E0;-3.104116765E-2;-1.739549231E0
1.416666667E0;-3.322785461E-2;-1.740279419E0
1.425000000E0;-3.599135975E-2;-1.742337105E0
1.433333333E0;-3.808925614E-2;-1.744682891E0
1.541666667E0;-7.108984101E-2;-1.839024730E0
1.550000000E0;-7.297102460E-2;-1.857275769E0
1.558333333E0;-7.571494352E-2;-1.870979850E0
1.566666667E0;-7.854608723E-2;-1.892338940E0
1.575000000E0;-8.274961995E-2;-1.897014288E0
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.2},
            xlabel=Time,
            ylabel=x,
            xticklabel style={inner xsep=0pt, anchor=west},
            xtick={0},
            after end axis/.code={
                \node at (axis cs:0,0) [anchor=east] {0};
            }
        ]
            \addplot[color=red,ultra thick] table [
                skip first n=1,
                col sep=semicolon,
                x=t,
                y=y
            ] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!