# Simple 1D plot using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

Trying to draw a 1D plot, some dots over one X axis. Currently, I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=22,
axis x line=bottom,% only show the bottom x axis
hide y axis,    
scatter/classes={%
    a={mark=o,draw=black}}
]

\addplot[scatter,only marks,
    mark size = 3pt,
    fill = red,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]
table {
3 0 
6 0 
9 0 
12 0 
15 0 
18 0 
    };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

unfortunately, the circles doesn't appears over (superposed) the x-axis. This is what I see:

[image]
Any hint or some solution more simple?

Comment: The circles appears over  the line of the X-axis (that is, superposed to it)?

Comment: @Dan: sorry, but no change in the result after adding ymin=0.

Comment: Use the `axis lines=middle` option in `\begin{axis}` as per [pgfplots: how make axes go through origin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62427/106162)

Comment: @Dan, with ymax=5 things goes even worst, the circles dissapears.

Comment: @DaiBowen: perfect, now circles appears over the line, as expected. Thanks a lot. Do you want it as answer or write a community answer in order to close the issue?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui it's the same answer as the question I linked to (you can see that more obviously in your MWE if you comment out the `hide y axis` instruction) so personally I think this question is best closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @DaiBowen: oops, sorry for the duplicate (but I can promise  I passed long time googling for the answer). Deleting this question in 4, 3, 2, ...

Comment: @pasabaporaqui not at all, it's not obviously a duplicate and I think even if marked as a duplicate there's good reason to not delete the question as it's coming at the same problem from a very different angle.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a y minimum and maximum.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=22,
    axis x line=bottom,% only show the bottom x axis
    hide y axis,    
    ymin=0,ymax=5,
    scatter/classes={%
        a={mark=o,draw=black}}
    ]

\addplot[scatter,only marks,
    mark size = 3pt,
    fill = red,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]
table {
3 0 
6 0 
9 0 
12 0 
15 0 
18 0 
    };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is it produces a lot of empty space over the line.

Comment: You can make it take up less empty space over the line by, e.g., adding `y=0.2cm,` after the `ymin=0,ymax=5,` line.