# Pgfplots: Axis through the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I do not know that my problem is but the axis of my graphs do not go through the origin.
I've read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62427/pgfplots-how-to-make-axes-go-through-the-origin) but it does not work for me.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis lines=middle]
\addplot {x^2+20};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and my output [image]

Maybe you can tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Right, it goes through (0,20) as you specified in `\addplot {x^2+20}; `. So is you question how to change the range of the y-axis?

Comment: No, I want that the x- and y-axis pass though (0,0) and draw the plot of y=x^2+20. Is this not possible?

Comment: y(0) = 0^2 + 20 = 20. No, it's not possible. Simple math ... // try instead `\addplot{x^2};` ...

Comment: You can specify `ymin=0` in the axis option

Comment: I think you do not understand my questions. I know that the graph passes through (0,20) but I want that the x-axis passes through (0,0) and not (0,20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `ymin=0` in the axis option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis lines=middle,ymin=0]
\addplot {x^2+20};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why "axis lines=middle" does not work?

Comment: As pointed out by @MS-SPO, it's due to the equation you are plotting: by default, axes are fitted.

Comment: Ok, so "axis lines=middle" does not force the axis to pass through (0,0). 
Is there a option for that in pgfplots?

Comment: You have to combine the options: `axis lines` and `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`

Comment: That is a bit disappointing. I assume the reason is that (0,0) is not part of my coordinate system.